# Python - div scraping where no tag is found

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm very new to python and a novice at development in general. I've been tasked with iterating through a div and I am able to get some data returned. However, when no tag exists I'm getting null results. Would anyone be able to help--I have researched and tried for days now? I truly appreciate your patience and explanations. I'm trying to extract the following:

- Start Date [ie, Sat 31 Jul 2021] which I get results from based on my code
- End Date [ie, Fri 20 Aug 2021] this one I get **no** results based on my code
- Description [ie, 20 Night New! Malta, The Adriatic & Greece] this one I get **no** results based on my code
- Ship Name [ie, Viking Sea] which I get results from based on my code

[image]

```html
<div class="cd-info"> <!-- Start cd-info -->
From <b>Sat 31 Jul 2021</b><br>
(To Fri 20 Aug 2021)<br>
<b>20 Night New! Malta, The Adriatic &amp; Greece</b><br>
Ship 
<a class="red" href="/cruise-ship-viking-sea.html">Viking Sea</a>
<br>
<span class="mobile-no-desktop-yes"><br></span>
More details at<br>
<a target="_blank" onclick="trackOutboundLink('https://www.vikingcruises.com/oceans/cruise-destinations/eastern-mediterranean/malta-adriatic-and-greece/index.html');" href="https://www.vikingcruises.com/oceans/cruise-destinations/eastern-mediterranean/malta-adriatic-and-greece/index.html">
<img class="noborder" src="/logos/viking-cruises.gif" alt="More details for 20 Night New! Malta, The Adriatic &amp; Greece at Viking Cruises">
</a>
</div>
```

Here is my code (no judgements please..haha)

````py
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = "https://www.cruisetimetables.com/cruisesearch.html?id=cse&sailmonth=Jul%202021&destination=Any&departureport=&arrivalport=&openjawcruise=&portofcall=&cruiseship=&duration=Any&chartercruise="
headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5"}
results = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

#initiate data storage
cruisestartdate = []
cruiseenddate = []
itinerarydescription = []
cruiseshipname = []
cruisecabinprice = []
destinationportname = []
portdatetime = []

cruise_div = soup.find_all('div', class_='cd-info')

#our loop through each container
for container in cruise_div:

         #cruise start date
         startdate = container.b.text
         print(startdate)
         cruisestartdate.append(startdate)

        # cruise end date
         enddate = container.string
         cruiseenddate.append(enddate)
        
            # ship name
         ship = container.a.text
         cruiseshipname.append(ship)

#pandas dataframe        
cruise = pd.DataFrame({
'Sail Date': cruisestartdate,
'End Date': cruiseenddate,
#'Description': description,
'Ship Name': cruiseshipname,
#'imdb': imdb_ratings,
#'metascore': metascores,
#'votes': votes,
#'us_grossMillions': us_gross,
})

print(soup)   
print(cruisestartdate)
print(cruiseenddate)
print(itinerarydescription)
print(cruiseshipname)```
````

**Here are my results from the print**:

> ['Sat 31 Jul 2021'] [None] [] ['Viking Sea']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution, using `bs4` API:

```py
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


# url = "https://www.cruisetimetables.com/cruisesearch.html?id=cse&sailmonth=Jul%202021&destination=Any&departureport=&arrivalport=&openjawcruise=&portofcall=&cruiseship=&duration=Any&chartercruise="
url = "https://www.cruisetimetables.com/cruisesearch.html?id=cse&sailmonth=Aug%202021&destination=Any&departureport=&arrivalport=&openjawcruise=&portofcall=&cruiseship=&duration=Any&chartercruise="
headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5"}
results = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.content, "html.parser")

all_data = []
for div in soup.select("div.cd-info"):
    from_ = div.b
    to_ = from_.find_next_sibling(text=True).strip()
    # remove (To )
    to_ = re.sub(r"\(To (.*)\)", r"\1", to_)

    desc = from_.find_next("b").get_text(strip=True)
    # remove html chars
    desc = BeautifulSoup(desc, "html.parser").get_text(strip=True)

    ship_name = div.a.get_text(strip=True)

    all_data.append(
        [
            from_.get_text(strip=True),
            to_,
            desc,
            ship_name,
        ]
    )


df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=["from", "to", "description", "ship name"])
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
              from               to                                                         description     ship name
0   Tue 3 Aug 2021  Mon 23 Aug 2021                          20 Night New! Malta, The Adriatic & Greece  Viking Venus
1  Tue 10 Aug 2021  Fri 20 Aug 2021                               10 Night New! Malta & Adriatic Jewels    Viking Sea
2  Tue 10 Aug 2021  Mon 30 Aug 2021                          20 Night New! Malta, The Adriatic & Greece    Viking Sea
3  Fri 13 Aug 2021  Fri 20 Aug 2021                                              7 Night Bermuda Escape  Viking Orion
4  Fri 13 Aug 2021  Mon 23 Aug 2021                         10 Night New! Malta & Greek Isles Discovery  Viking Venus
5  Fri 13 Aug 2021   Thu 2 Sep 2021                          20 Night New! Malta, The Adriatic & Greece  Viking Venus
6  Sat 14 Aug 2021  Sat 21 Aug 2021                                    7 Night Iceland's Natural Beauty    Viking Sky
7  Mon 16 Aug 2021  Mon 13 Sep 2021                   28 Night Star Collector: From Greek Gods to Gaudí     Wind Surf
8  Mon 16 Aug 2021   Fri 3 Sep 2021              18 Night Star Collector: Flamenco of the Mediterranean     Wind Surf
9  Mon 16 Aug 2021  Wed 29 Sep 2021  44 Night Star Collector: Myths & Masterpieces of the Mediterranean     Wind Surf
```

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

---

EDIT: To scrape the data from all pages:

```py
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US, en;q=0.5"}
# url = "https://www.cruisetimetables.com/cruisesearch.html?id=cse&sailmonth=Jul%202021&destination=Any&departureport=&arrivalport=&openjawcruise=&portofcall=&cruiseship=&duration=Any&chartercruise="
url = "https://www.cruisetimetables.com/cruisesearch.html?id=cse&sailmonth=Aug%202021&destination=Any&departureport=&arrivalport=&openjawcruise=&portofcall=&cruiseship=&duration=Any&chartercruise="

offset = 1
all_data = []
while True:
    u = url + f"&offset={offset}"
    print(f"Getting offset {offset=}")

    results = requests.get(u, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.content, "html.parser")

    for div in soup.select("div.cd-info"):
        from_ = div.b
        to_ = from_.find_next_sibling(text=True).strip()
        # remove (To )
        to_ = re.sub(r"\(To (.*)\)", r"\1", to_)

        desc = from_.find_next("b").get_text(strip=True)
        # remove html chars
        desc = BeautifulSoup(desc, "html.parser").get_text(strip=True)

        ship_name = div.a.get_text(strip=True)

        all_data.append(
            [
                from_.get_text(strip=True),
                to_,
                desc,
                ship_name,
            ]
        )

    # get next offset:
    offset = soup.select_one(".cd-buttonlist > b + a")
    if offset:
        offset = int(offset.get_text(strip=True).split("-")[0])
    else:
        break


df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=["from", "to", "description", "ship name"])
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
Getting offset offset=1
Getting offset offset=11
Getting offset offset=21

...

                from               to                                                                      description                 ship name
0     Tue 3 Aug 2021  Mon 23 Aug 2021                                       20 Night New! Malta, The Adriatic & Greece              Viking Venus
1    Tue 10 Aug 2021  Fri 20 Aug 2021                                            10 Night New! Malta & Adriatic Jewels                Viking Sea
2    Tue 10 Aug 2021  Mon 30 Aug 2021                                       20 Night New! Malta, The Adriatic & Greece                Viking Sea
3    Fri 13 Aug 2021  Fri 20 Aug 2021                                                           7 Night Bermuda Escape              Viking Orion

...

144  Tue 31 Aug 2021   Tue 7 Sep 2021                                                           7 Nights Mediterranean             MSC Splendida
145  Tue 31 Aug 2021   Tue 7 Sep 2021                                    7 Nachte Grose Freiheit - Schwedische Kuste 1             Mein Schiff 6
146  Tue 31 Aug 2021   Tue 7 Sep 2021                                                 7 Night Iceland's Natural Beauty            Viking Jupiter
```

Comment: @Andrej--wow, you're a superstar. I'm truly overwhelmed and grateful for your response and everyone else too. Thanks so much.

Comment: If I wanted to return results through months, years and multiple pages is that possible without having to change the url each time?

As I go through each month I now notice that returns the first 10 results of that month and there are 300+ total spaced out 10 per page. The next url returns results 11 thru 20 and so on: https://www.cruisetimetables.com/cruisesearch.html?id=cse&sailmonth=Oct%202021&destination=Any&departureport=&arrivalport=&openjawcruise=&portofcall=&cruiseship=&duration=Any&chartercruise=&offset=11

Comment: @viperone I've updated my answer how to scrape the data from multiple pages (increasing the `offset=` URL parameter).

Comment: @Andrej--absolutely awesome. Thank you so much. You're a life saver and really taught me a lot. I truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

`container.text` is a nicely formatted list of lines.  Just splitit and use the pieces:

```
cruise_div = soup.find_all('div', class_='cd-info')

#our loop through each container
for container in cruise_div:
    lines = container.text.splitlines()

    cruisestartdate.append(lines[1])

    cruiseenddate.append(lines[2])

    itinerarydescription.append(lines[3])
    
    # ship name
    ship = container.a.text
    cruiseshipname.append(ship)
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim Roberts!

Answer (score 0):

Getting the start date, description, and ship name are straightforward. The only trick here is to get the end date which does lie inside a specific tag. To get it, you have to tweak some regex. Here is one solution similar to @Andrej's:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """
<div class="cd-info"> <!-- Start cd-info -->
From <b>Sat 31 Jul 2021</b><br>
(To Fri 20 Aug 2021)<br>
<b>20 Night New! Malta, The Adriatic &amp; Greece</b><br>
Ship 
<a class="red" href="/cruise-ship-viking-sea.html">Viking Sea</a>
<br>
<span class="mobile-no-desktop-yes"><br></span>
More details at<br>
<a target="_blank" onclick="trackOutboundLink('https://www.vikingcruises.com/oceans/cruise-destinations/eastern-mediterranean/malta-adriatic-and-greece/index.html');" href="https://www.vikingcruises.com/oceans/cruise-destinations/eastern-mediterranean/malta-adriatic-and-greece/index.html">
<img class="noborder" src="/logos/viking-cruises.gif" alt="More details for 20 Night New! Malta, The Adriatic &amp; Greece at Viking Cruises">
</a>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
bold = soup.find_all('b')
print(f"Start date: {bold[0].text}")
print(f"Description: {bold[1].text}")

untagged_line = re.sub("\n", "", soup.find(text=re.compile('To')))
end_date = re.sub(r"\(To (.*)\)", r"\1", untagged_line)
print(f"End date: {end_date}")

ship = soup.find('a', class_='red')
print(f"Ship: {ship.text}")
```

- Output:

```
Start date: Sat 31 Jul 2021
Description: 20 Night New! Malta, The Adriatic & Greece
End date: Fri 20 Aug 2021
Ship: Viking Sea
```

Comment: @viperone You're welcome! Could you accept the answer if that's what you're looking for? Appreciate it!